# how do i create a list when retrieving a list from a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am looking up a set of email addresses grouped together in a dictionary using the get() function

the get function returns

```
['[“one.yahoo.com”,”two.yahoo.com”,"three.yahoo.com"]']
```

I have tried several methods to remove the single quotes so that I end up with a list like this

```
email = [ [“one.yahoo.com”,”two.yahoo.com”,"three.yahoo.com"] ]
```

the dictionary looks like this

dict= { 'Warehouse':'[“x@yahoo.com”,”y@yahoo.com”,”z@yahoo.com”]',
'Bottling':'[“one.yahoo.com”,”two.yahoo.com”,"three.yahoo.com"]'}

Comment: just wanted to check that do you need list inside list or just return list?

Comment: if only list required you can just do it with  json.loads(listA[0]).  So it will convert string into dictionary. or you can do json.dumps(listA[0]) for json.

Comment: you can try  json.loads(listA[0]) as suggested by akash senta or you can try to use eval as eval(listA[0])

Comment: yes, I am looking for a list within a list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert string representation of list to a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/how-to-convert-string-representation-of-list-to-a-list)

Comment: it will be better to answer if you are adding a sample of dictionary

Comment: I've tried all 15 solutions offered and none have worked

Comment: Can you try my answer?

Comment: btw https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import ast # This contains a function to convert str to list
email = ['["one.yahoo.com", "two.yahoo.com", "three.yahoo.com"]']
email = str(email) # Converts to str type.
email = email.replace("'", "") # Replaces the apostrophes with blanks.
email = ast.literal_eval(email) # Converts to list. 
print(email)
```

Output is:

```
[["one.yahoo.com", "two.yahoo.com", "three.yahoo.com"]]
```

Comment: Fixed that. ast should convert it back to list.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
email = ['["one.yahoo.com","two.yahoo.com","three.yahoo.com"]']

email = email[0].replace('"','')
email = email[1:-1].split(",")
```

Hope this may be of help.